# How to get the colorFormats supported by MediaCodec on android 4.1 and 4.2?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

On android 4.1 and above, I intend to get the list of `colorFormats` supported by a particular `MediaCodec`.

Android 4.3 and above provides an API ([public MediaCodecInfo getCodecInfo ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#getCodecInfo())) to get the `MediaCodecInfo` associated with a particular instance of `MediaCodec`. Furthermore, I am able to call [getCapabilitiesForType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.html#getCapabilitiesForType(java.lang.String)) on this `MediaCodecInfo` object which will fetch me associated `MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities` object, on which I call API [colorFormats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html#colorFormats) to get the list of color-formats for my `MediaCodec` object.

Now, I'm not able to execute above sequence of calls on android 4.1 and 4.2 simply because the `MediaCodec` API [getCodecInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#getCodecInfo()) is added in API level 18.

Could anyone suggest how can I achieve the same OR any other method to get the list of color-formats on android 4.1 and 4.2.

Comment: There's no public way to query for the info.  See http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#q9 for some other notes on life pre-API 18.

Comment: Hi Fadden, thanks for your reply. I knew it's not supported on android 4.1 and 4.2 however I went ahead asking the question hoping to get another direction to get the colorFormats for a particular MediaCodec obj. :)

Comment: Is there be a possibility to somehow simulate `INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED` and get the OutputFormat using `getOutputFormat()`. Then call `getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT)` on this `MediaFormat` object to get the color format supported by the decoder?

Comment: Your best bet may be to probe for it -- try each color format in turn and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is an elegant way to get the color-format supported by the particular MediaCodec instance in use, that works on android 4.1 and above. Same is explained below:

While doing `dequeueOutputBuffer` look out for error-code: `MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED`. Upon receiving this error code, call `getOutputFormat` on the codec and subsequently call `getInteger` on the received `MediaFormat` object with string [KEY_COLOR_FORMAT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat.html#KEY_COLOR_FORMAT) to get the color-format.

Comment: Yes, for decoders that's what you should do, since you can't know which one of the supported formats a decoder is going to use. For encoders you can't use this approach though - there you need to know the format beforehand, and MediaCodecList is the only solution. I assumed you were asking about encoders since that's where getCodecInfo is most vital.

Answer (score 3):

For Android 4.1 and 4.2, you need to use the `MediaCodecList` class to iterate through the available codecs - there you'll get the `MediaCodecInfo` that will provide the same information as `getCodecInfo()` does.

The only case where `getCodecInfo()` (or `getName()`) is needed if you've created the codec using `createEncoderByType` (or `createDecoderByType`) in which case you don't know which codec you're actually dealing with. At least in AOSP, both of these functions just return the first codec in `MediaCodecList` that matches the provided MIME type. (Some manufacturers might of course have customized this but I don't see much reason for it.)

Thus - on 4.1 and 4.2 - instead of using `createEncoderByType`, manually iterate through the codecs in `MediaCodecList` and pick the first one matching your MIME type, and get the info and capabilities there.

So, simply put - if you currently have this code:

```
MediaCodec codec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(mimeType);
MediaCodecInfo info = codec.getCodecInfo();
```

Then the equivalent version that supports 4.1 and 4.2 as well is:

```
MediaCodecInfo info = null;
for (int i = 0; i < MediaCodecList.getCodecCount() && info == null; i++) {
    MediaCodecInfo curInfo = MediaCodecList.getCodecInfoAt(i);
    if (!curInfo.isEncoder())
        continue;
    String[] types = curInfo.getSupportedTypes();
    for (int j = 0; j < types.length; j++)
        if (types[j].equals(mimeType))
            info = curInfo;
}
MediaCodec codec = MediaCodec.createByCodecName(info.getName());
```

Comment: Hi there.. thanks for your input on this. In my case, I am creating a codec `byType` and like you said I can not call `getCodecInfo` or `getName()` on android 4.1 and 4.2. Ultimately, I want to know the colorFormats supported by the codec I've created (on android 4.1+).

Comment: Well, then instead of creating the codec with a `byType` function, use `MediaCodecList` to manually choose a codec. (The "logic" for choosing a codec that the `byType` functions use is picking the first matching one.) When you choose it manually via `MediaCodecList`, you can easily get the info for the codec from `MediaCodecList` - then create this codec using `MediaCodec.createByCodecName` instead.

Comment: Thus, the `createEncoderByType` function is basically impossible to use safely on versions prior to 4.3, because you can't guess the supported color formats. That's why I contributed the `getCodecInfo()` and `getName()` functions that became available as part of 4.3. (Also, in practice many encoders misinterpret the input color formats on devices prior to 4.3, since there were no CTS tests, so in practice it's very hard to write code that works on any device, prior to 4.3.)

Comment: Very thoughtful approach there. However the only problem that I see with this is - More often than not many devices will have more than one Codec to decode a certain mime type and calling `createDecoderByType` ensures that an instance of optimized Codec instance (from the viable Codec-set for that mime-type) is created for the particular platform. Ensuring this would be highly unlikely using `createByCodecName`.

Comment: No, `createDecoderByType` or `createEncoderByType` doesn't do any special magic - I already wrote this in the initial answer, they just pick the first matching codec. The decision of choosing the most optimized codec is done by the manufacturer when they put the codecs in the right priority order in /etc/media_codecs.xml. (The source that ultimately picks the codec if you use the `ByType` functions is at  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/777ee5e/media/libstagefright/OMXCodec.cpp, lines 182-233, called with flags=0.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable input. Your confirmation about codecs being put in priority-wise in media_codecs.xml allowed me to go ahead and write a function to get the color-format used by the platform-selected codec, obtained using `byType`(also the 1st matching codec in xml) for a particular mime type. Cheers :)

Comment: Hi mstorsjo, although the approach suggested by you works well (given the OEM has done its part properly :)) it still is prone of few corner cases where the color-format of output data may change. Also, I find the approach I have mentioned in my answer a more cleaner and dependable one. Having said that, I appreciate the support you had extended in this regard earlier. I will update my findings in my answer shall I find any new surprises :)

Comment: PS: I was working with `MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED` and `getOutputFormat` combination before too however because of a minor bug in my code it didn't work earlier and today after correcting that it started working like a charm.